# Escape a path with ".." (parent) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, path

I have a string that denotes a full path (note this is on OSX, but i believe it should have a similar solution for any OS):

```
var path = "/Some/Path/../Projects/iOS/ThirdParty/myPath";
```

Checking this path to see if it exists returns false:

```
Directory.Exists(path) // return false
```

Is there any built-in helper method or class that can help translating this into a full path that does not contain ".." ?

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to convert a relative path to an absolute one. You can use [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this:

```
var relativePath = "/Some/Path/../Projects/iOS/ThirdParty/myPath";
var absolutePath = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm off to become a farmer in rural Iowa (they do farming there right? As a Brit I have no idea...)

Answer (score -3):

in the statement var path = "/Some/Path/../Projects/iOS/ThirdParty/myPath";

'/' acts as a escape character, you need to declare the statement by appending @ symbol at the beginning like below.

var path = @"/Some/Path/../Projects/iOS/ThirdParty/myPath";

Comment: `/` is not an escape character. You may be thinking of `\\`